# JAVA Spring ResultSetExtractor ERROR... I might be missing a jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor

Comment: Add the jar to your runtime classpath!!!! If its an web-app , put all Spring jars and dependent jars inside `WEB-INF/lib`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add spring-jdbc.jar and its dependency spring-tx.jar to your WEB-INF/lib